# Unable to CRUD in aspnetboilerplate

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Currently, I am working on a solution developed by AspNetBoilerplate framework. I am facing an issue that the CRUD operations are not performed correctly when the website is published on server. Interestingly there is not error in localhost !

[See image please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGltL.png)

Comment: Check the error in Logs.txt.

Comment: Firstly, you have to check **Request Payload** in _Network_ tab to find out the details of your request. Then, you can find details in **Response**  tab.

Answer (score 0):

The general routine of tracking a request from Client to Database in AspNetBoilerplate is defined below :

Firstly, you have to check **Request Payload** in *Network* tab to find out the details of your request. Then, you can find details in **Response**  tab. After that, you can check the `dbo.AuditLogs` table in order to get some details about the exception. Please note that the Update service is not marked with `DisableAuditing` attribute.